# ajax function call for message sending giving 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Following is the code which calls the ajax function to send msg to to the user when the following code triggered gives 500 internal server error jquery.min.js
the files are hosted in amazon aws. when the same code is tested in normal bigrock server it is working fine, when hosted in amazon its giving 500 internal server error.

```
function sendotp(){
var vl = parseInt($('#otp').val());      
    var contact = $('#contact').val(); 
            //alert(contact);
        $.ajax({
        url: "validation.php", 
        type:'POST',
         data: {
                contact: contact,vals : vl
            },
        success: function(data){

        }
    });

}
```

Below is the php code in validation.php

```
if(isset($_POST['contact']))
{
 $otp = $_POST['vals'];
     $contact_number = explode('-',$_POST['contact']);
     $number = $contact_number[1];
     $sms = "Your OTP Varification Code For Wrap2Earn Registration is ".$otp.".";

/*  sms Integration  */
//Your authentication key
$authKey = "XXXXX";

//Multiple mobiles numbers separated by comma
$mobileNumber = $number;

//Sender ID,While using route4 sender id should be 6 characters long.
$senderId = "XXXXXX";

//Your message to send, Add URL encoding here.
$message = urlencode("$sms");

//Define route
$route = "4";
//Prepare you post parameters
$postData = array(
    'authkey' => $authKey,
    'mobiles' => $mobileNumber,
    'message' => $message,
    'sender' => $senderId,
    'route' => $route
);

//API URL
$url="https://control.msg91.com/api/sendhttp.php";

// init the resource
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
    //,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
));


//Ignore SSL certificate verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


//get response
$output = curl_exec($ch);

//Print error if any
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: is `curl` enabled?

Comment: yup its enabled in server

Comment: where is `validation.php` hosted ?

Comment: in amazon ec2 server

Comment: thank you jaromanda X i reinstalled curl and enabled its working fine now